# How to (re)enable YouTube videos on Safari with Flash plugin 10.2?

Tags: safari, adobe-flash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The browser doesn't show videos on Youtube](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/the-browser-doesnt-show-videos-on-youtube)

[Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/) videos appear as a black box only in safari 5.0.3, since flash payer has been updated to 10.2. They work if I change the *User Agent* to *Safari 4.0.3* using the *Developer* menu, but this is not permanent.

Flash Player 10.1 is no longer downloadable, so I don't know how to downgrade. User agent setting are not permanent, or I don't know how to set them fixed.

Maybe, it is a bug in YouTube embedding, because Flash sites like [that from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) work. I am relativly sure that the new flash plugin is the problem, because I have to macbooks with OS X 10.6.6 and Safari 5.0.3. The only difference if the version of the flash plugin: 10.1 shows youtube videos, 10.2 not.

I'm not sure the flash version is the reason. ALso the working mac has been installed with OS X 10.6 from scratch, the not working has been updated from an 10.5.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/the-browser-doesnt-show-videos-on-youtube

Comment: I have the same problem - just updated to flash 10.2 and voila - black box in you tube!
Works ok in firefox - must be a safari-flash issue ?

Comment: [I also have the black rectangle Flash bug in Safari](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/139517/how-to-have-safari-play-again-flash-videos?rq=1), and this is not the first time. And I am not the only one. This is really a crappy bug. It is working, I change nothing, and *suddenly* it does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem while running ClickToFlash 1.6b9 (the original general browser plug-in, not the Safari 5.x extension). Even with ClickToFlash  disabled via the checkbox in ClickToFlash's preferences, it still happened. I ended up dragging the ClickToFlash plug-in out of `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/` and restarting Safari, and it went away.

Comment: I do not have installed ClickToFlash.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start Safari in 32Bit mode (right click on it, chose "information" and check "32-bit mode".

Another idea: uninstall flash completely so safari should display HTML5 videos in youtube without a plugin.

Hope, that helps!

Comment: Uninstall Flash is not a possibility in the moment, because other sites do not support HTML 5 in the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fix the bad version of Flash that you have, but I can offer a solution to get YouTube working. YouTube supports formats other than Flash. If you are using Safari, download and install this Safari 5 Plugin called [YouTube5](http://www.verticalforest.com/youtube5-extension/)

Once this extension is installed in Safari 5, when you go to the YouTube site, instead of getting flash videos you get a custom HTML5 player. Works great and I don't miss flash.

Here is a screen shot of how I have it setup in my Safari 5 Extensions panel of Preferences.

[image: Safari 5 Extension Preference Panel]

Hope this helps!

Comment: As I understand, "YouTube5" is an extension, not a plug-in.