# The browser doesn't show videos on Youtube

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, safari

Today I noticed that Safari doesn't show anymore the videos shown on Youtube; I just see a black rectangle, and when I try to use the popup menu in that area, it doesn't appear.

As far as I can remember, one week ago I was able to see videos on Youtube. Something is changed in this week; for what I can remember, Safari has not been updated, in these days.

How can I find the reason of the problem, and eventually resolve it?

Comment: I don't have the same problem with Google Chrome.

Comment: Is this question related to [this one](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/how-to-reenable-youtube-videos-on-safari-with-flash-plugin-10-2)?

Comment: The Adobe site reports I have version 10.1.102.64 of the plugin, not 10.2; the other question is referring to version 10.2.

Comment: I just think, its is the 10.2 Flash version. Maybe there is any other difference. Have you tried the User agent trick?

Comment: @Arne Burmeiser: If you write that as answer, I will accept it; changing the user agent to "Safari 5.0.3 — Windows" worked. If I set it to "Safari 5.0.3 — Mac", or I let Safari choose it automatically, I don't see Youtube videos anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the [same problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/how-to-reenable-youtube-videos-on-safari-with-flash-plugin-10-2) and the only solution I have in the moment is to change the *User Agent* using the *Developer* Menu. *Safari 4.1.3 - Mac* works for me. But this is not permanent! You have to change it every time yu start Safari :-(

Comment: I updated Adobe Flash, and for some days I had to manually set the _User Agent_ string. Today, all in a sudden, I started to see the videos on Youtube even when I left the _User Agent_ string set to the default value ("Automatically Choosen").

Answer (score 1):

Are you using flash or html5 youtube?

I recommend to try the html5 version, if you are not using it already.

Answer (score -1):

Could it be that Adobe Flash has crashed? Are you running the latest version?

Also in this time have you restarted Safari/your Mac? If not that may get Flash working again.

Comment: I reset the Mac, installed the latest version of the Flash plug-in, but I still cannot see Youtube videos. I don't have any problems watching the Flash animations that are in the [Adobe Flash page](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/).

Comment: Actually, sometimes I need to change the _User Agent_ string, and sometimes I don't need to do it. I still have to understand I have to change the _User Agent_ string the second time I access Youtube, or if that depends from the video being watched.

Comment: If Flash had crashed he would have seen the crash dialog.