# How to have Safari play again Flash videos?

Tags: safari, video, bug, adobe-flash, plugins

Safari has suddenly stopped to load Flash videos.

On YouTube, for instance : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJENlHEZi18

On another site too.

In place of the video, I just have a black rectangle.

In Activity Monitor, I do not see any Flash plug-in process.

So I guess the bug is in Safari.

Anyway, I did clear the Flash data in the System Prefs. To no avail.

It was working yesterday. Now it is broken. I did not change the prefs. I did not quit Safari.

This random bug is really annoying. I have reported it to Apple.

In the meantime, how can I have Safari load Flash videos again ?

Thank you.

I have Safari 5.1.10 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: This bug occurs often now !

Comment: This bug occurs also with Firefox. How can I have Firefox play again Flash videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One solution :*

**Kill the process *Safari Web Content*.** *Warning :* In all pages, you will lose all the data you may have entered.

*Explanation :*

The process *Safari Web Content* has just been killed without human intervention. And Safari reloads all the pages. This is a bug in Safari. It happens from time to time, when many pages are loaded, it is a kind of process apoptosis. Now, I have the Flash Player plug-in process running, and Safari loads the Flash videos. :-)

*Confirmation :*

The bug has occurred again. This time, I have killed the process *Safari Web Content* myself. This solution works.

[Edited : Confirmation of the solution]